# How to return the index of the array items occuring under a certain threshold

Tags: ruby, arrays

In Ruby, given an array of elements, what is the easiest way to return the indices of the elements that are not identical?

```
array = ['a','b','a','a','a','c'] #=> [1,5]
```

---

Expanded question:

Assuming that the identity threshold is based on the most frequent element in the array.

```
array =  ['a','c','a','a','a','d','d'] #=> [1,5,6]
```

For an array with two equally frequent elements, return the indices of either of the 2 elements. e.g.

```
array = ['a','a','a','b','b','b'] #=>[0,1,2] or #=> [3,4,5]
```

Comment: Is it known what the "same elements" are (in your example, is it known that we are looking for anything except `"a"` or is that to be inferred from the number of occurences of `"a"` versus anything else in the array)?

Comment: Assuming the 'same elements' are not known and need to be inferred from the array. In which case if nothing is same or identical, it should return the indices of the whole array.

Comment: What if there are 5 "a" and 5 "b", what should be returned? Please expand your question by giving a few examples of input and the desired outputs.

Comment: Good catch there, in the problem domain am working on, i dont expect that to happen... in case it does, we can rescue it with an message that raises such a case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer edited after question edit:

```
def idx_by_th(arr)
    idx = [] 
    occur = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |k,v| k[v] += 1; k }
    th = arr.sort_by { |v| occur[v] }.last
    arr.each_index {|i| idx << i if arr[i]!=th}
    idx
end

idx_by_th ['a','b','a','a','a','c']  # => [1, 5]
idx_by_th ['a','c','a','a','a','d','d'] # => [1, 5, 6]
idx_by_th ['a','a','a','b','b','b'] # => [0, 1, 2]
```

---

These answers are valid for the first version of the question:

ruby < 1.8.7

```
def get_uniq_idx(arr)
    test=[]; idx=[]
    arr.each_index do |i|
        idx << i if !(arr[i+1..arr.length-1] + test).include?(arr[i])
        test << arr[i]
    end
    return idx
end

puts get_uniq_idx(['a','b','a','a','a','c']).inspect # => [1, 5]
```

---

ruby >= 1.8.7:

```
idxs=[]
array.each_index {|i| idxs<<i if !(array.count(array[i]) > 1)}
puts idxs.inspect # => [1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you're looking for, but is something like this what you want?

```
array = ['a','b','a','a','a','c']
array.uniq.inject([]) do |arr, elem| 
  if array.count(elem) == 1
    arr << array.index(elem)
  end
  arr
end

# => [1,5]
```